# TypeScript considers prototype of class provided to mixin as 'any'

Tags: typescript, mixins, typeof

I want to use the class that I provide to a mixin as the type for a parameter to a method of the class I return from that mixin.

For example, I want the `method1` is this example to use `BaseClass` as the type for it's argument:

```js
class BaseClass {
    a = 123;
}

class SomeClass extends Mixin(BaseClass) {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // Should be of type 'BaseClass'
        this.method1({
            a: "aaa"
        })
    }
}
```

I came up with this solution:

```js
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class BaseClass {
    a = 123;
}

export function Mixin<T extends Constructor>(ExtendedClass: T) {
    return class extends ExtendedClass {
        method1(baseClass: typeof ExtendedClass.prototype) { }
    }
}

class SomeClass extends Mixin(BaseClass) {
    constructor() {
        super()
        // doesn't give compilation errors since baseClass is 'any'
        this.method1({
            a: "aaa"
        })
        // gives compilation error as expected
        this.method2({
            a: "aaa"
        })
    }
    method2(baseClass: typeof BaseClass.prototype) { }
}
```

The problem is TypeScript `method1` treats `typeof BaseClass.prototype` as `any` and not `BaseClass` which is the case of `method2`.

I would expect both `method1` and `method2` to behave the same. Why aren't they? And, is there a way I can get `method1` to behave like `method2`?

[<del>Playground</del>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUAvFAN4C+AfCVAhAO5QAUAdOwIaoDmSAXFA4IQAbQC6AShI0CAbgBQ8zABsOSJFABCaiDFXry8qMcG0AjACYAzAoqKIADzC5gUAGboE2AJaIoAWW8HbwRCKEdgCAQAEw14ZDQsHFQqZm0kXX1+KAIpMiMTVAhgdFQEKBU1DQio2K0dPSrDExaoAFtigAs4aLNmACMGrIFQSDg3eozG9VYwVDgcUYg8qDsWuzslLKgAZTgO6eqHSJiNQOCENKGqvILjTEQUDGxcZlvWkyR0SFQ3u9aAPQAqDROAQJAIADkrm43gAbtAHm0wN5VMBfOUIKh5qgNEgQphoIMpttvBpIUIQJD-i1gJ0yawOnSen18h8PhwBAAiDi8rk0kwUCQC4xAqCwhEaJEotEY8LY3CCI6QbAQaIiqB0hlM7rRCzMNnslqcqA8vkaoX-NYmHU9fXEzJVEbgCDjSaOmZzBYLF0rDaKIA)

[Playground (Version 2)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUAvFAN4C+AfCVAhAO5QAUAdOwIaoDmSAXFA4IQAbQC6AShI0CAbgBQ8zABsOSJFABCaiDFXry8qMcG0AjACYAzAoqKIADzC5gUAGboE2AJaIoAWW8HbwRCKEdgCAQAEw14ZDQsHFQqZgBlOABbXX1+KAIpMiMTVAhgdFQEKBU1DQio2K0dPVrDE3aobOAACzhos2YAI2bcgVBIODcoDOyW9VYwVDgccYhCqDt2uzslXOmsnNb6mI1A4IRmbSRD9ULi40xEFAxsXGY7jpMkdEhUd-uOgB6QFQaJwCBIBAAclc3G8ADdoI9MmBvKpgL4qhBUEtUBokCFMNBhtc5hpvBooUIQFCAe0ehTWF1ev1mEVPp8OAIAEQcPncukmCgSQXGYFQOGIjTI1HozHhHG4QR1JwQbAQaKiqAMpBMsosixsrXtLlQXn8rXCgGbEzMvqGkk3PKrSZNUm5BZLFbgNbkDbyOxAA)

Comment: Do you want to be able to pass in the actual class or an instance of the class to these methods?

Comment: An object with the interface of `BaseClass`.

Comment: just use `BaseClass` instead of `typeof BaseClass.prototype`

Comment: typescript doesn't actually check the actual type but checks the **shape** of the types.

Comment: Ok, my example is confusing. If you check my revised Playground you will see what the problem is that I am trying to solve.

Comment: They are different because `ExtendedClass` is generic and inherits its `prototype` from `Function` which has type `any`; it essentially prematurely evaluates it.  I'd suggest changing to `InstanceType<ExtendedClass>` which will be deferred, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6LAvm).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: That solves my problem. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it. I read up on `InstanceType`. When you create a class two types are created: the interface and the constructor function. `InstanceType` allows you to return the former. Thanks!